# Sending Python array to django template by AJAX

Tags: python, arrays, ajax, django

Im trying to send a random Python array to a template in Django by using AJAX:

JS:

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/hello",
            type: "get",
            success: function(data) { 
                printData(data);                    
            },
            error: function(data) { 
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    })
```

Django view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

import numpy as np

def hello(request):
    rand_arr = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
    return HttpResponse(rand_arr)
```

I receive the array as a string like: 3133352430290167691. Is it possible to receive it as an array, and access the individual values?

Comment: You should dump the array to json before returning it. `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(rand_arr))`

Comment: I tried that before: TypeError at /hello/
array([35, 54, 73, 78, 14, 38,  5, 86, 47, 92]) is not JSON serializable

Comment: So why are you using numpy here? Just use a standard Python list.

Comment: Perhaps you could cast it to a python list. Or just use a list to being with. `rand_arr = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]`

Comment: Now I receive it like: [86, 58, 36, 98, 46, 79, 11, 75, 75, 83]. But I cant use it as an array in JS. It is handled as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return json in your HTTP response. Also, it is uneccesary to use numpy to create an array. This can easily be done with `random`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

import random
import json

def hello(request):
    rand_arr = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(rand_arr), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I receive: [77, 17, 81, 58, 20, 23, 50, 59, 6, 83], but I can't access the values.It seems to be handles as a string.

Comment: Edited my post, I omitted the content type. The javascript should be able to handle it now.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach would be to use both Dajax and Dajaxice. It's a more "pythonic" way to create dynamic pages via AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

If you need Numpy (and that variable `rand_arr` was an example) then the reason using `json.dumps(rand_array)` fails is because Numpy returns its own Array type `numpy.ndarray`.

The way to work this with Numpy, then, is to turn the array into a list.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

import json
import numpy as np

def hello(request):
    rand_arr = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(rand_arr)), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: TypeError at /hello/
44 is not JSON serializable

Comment: Not JSON serializable? That error is caused by using `json.dumps`. I have tried this code and it works.

Comment: I used np.array.tolist() to slove it.

Comment: I wonder why I was downvoted, since I was the only one to contemplate the fact that you wanted to transform a Numpy array to JSON, not a Python list. I can only imagine we're using different versions of Numpy which allows me to just call `list(array)` on the array while you had to use `array.tolist()`.